# Watch expression does not work in modal included

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-scope, watch, angularjs-ng-include

i just want to make work a watch expression into a modal , which is included in a html file .

Into my demo, there are 2 watches : one works and the other no.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bNF7Yw?p=info

Thank you

Comment: I get "Import error - Plunk not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`includemodal` should be under the scope of the ModalInstanceController since that model in defined under the template that is used for the modal. [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sQWg5nu0tFqHSnPH2IIf?p=preview)

```
$scope.openAddProductModal = function ( ) {   
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'AddProductModalContent.html',
              controller:  function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log) {
                $scope.includemodal={search_value:''};

                $scope.$watch('includemodal.search_value', function(new_val) {
                  console.log('includemodal.search_value ' + new_val);
                });

               $scope.ok = function () {
                $modalInstance.close();
               };

              $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
              };
           },
            resolve: {

            }
          });
  };
```